# advice moving code in JSP to a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been starting to learn JavaEE and programming in general. I have created 6 different JSP programs so far. I am getting comfortable with it and now want to do things better. I understand that I need to reduce the amount of code in my JPS. I am including a common program in JSP form and would like pointers on what parts should go where within the servlet or how to look at this (should I make a bunch of classes then use the servlet to put them together or run the whole thing with a servlet :/).
I am putting my initial thoughts in the code with each section.
Please don't hand me answers, I need to struggle to learn - but please get me moving not staying stagnate.

```
<%@ page language="java" import ="java.util.*" import="java.math.*" %>

<html>

<head><title>TicTacToe</title></head>

<body>

<h1>TicTacToe</h1>

<% // game state variables to include in the servlet I think
char[][] tiles; // the board
String winner;  
tiles = (char[][]) session.getAttribute("tiles");
winner = (String)session.getAttribute("winner"); 
if (tiles == null || winner == null) {
tiles = new char[3][3];
for (int r=0; r<3; r++) 
  for (int c=0; c<3; c++) 
    tiles[r][c] = ' ';
  winner = new String(""); //not too sure how this should change, I am thinking I would need a class for "winner" maybe
  }
  %>

  <%  // All things dealing with display I am thinking Servlet under processRequest 
  if (request.getParameter("reset") != null) {
for (int r=0; r<3; r++) 
  for (int c=0; c<3; c++) 
    tiles[r][c] = ' ';
winner = new String("");
  }
  %>

  <%  // Pretty sure this needs a person class, maybe put both this one and the "O" player in the same class. 
 boolean didX = false;
 if (winner.equals("")) {
  for (int r=0; r<3; r++) { 
  for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
    if (request.getParameter("B" + r + c) != null && tiles[r][c] == '     ') {
      tiles[r][c] = 'X';
      didX = true;
    }
   }
  }
 } 
 if (didX) { //thinking ether a winner class to check both or run this in the servlet
// see if "X" player won yet
for (int r=0; r<3; r++) {
  if (tiles[r][0]=='X' && tiles[r][1]=='X' && tiles[r][2] == 'X') {
     winner = new String("X");
  }
  }
  for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
  if (tiles[0][c]=='X' && tiles[1][c]=='X' && tiles[2][c] == 'X') {
     winner = new String("X");
  }
   }
   if (tiles[0][0]=='X' && tiles[1][1]=='X' && tiles[2][2] == 'X') {
   winner = new String("X");
   }
   if (tiles[0][2]=='X' && tiles[1][1]=='X' && tiles[2][0] == 'X') {
  winner = new String("X");
  }
  }

  // same as with "X" player
  if (didX && winner.equals("")) {
  boolean playable = false;
  for (int r=0; r<3; r++) for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
  if (tiles[r][c] == ' ') {
    playable = true;
  }
  }
  if (playable) {
  boolean didO = false;
  while (!didO) {
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    int c = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    if (tiles[r][c] == ' ') {
      tiles[r][c] = 'O';
      didO = true;
    }
    }

     // same as with "X" 
    for (int r=0; r<3; r++) {
    if (tiles[r][0]=='O' && tiles[r][1]=='O' && tiles[r][2] == 'O') {
       winner = new String("O");
    }
    }
    for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
    if (tiles[0][c]=='O' && tiles[1][c]=='O' && tiles[2][c] == 'O') {
      winner = new String("O");
      }
    }
    if (tiles[0][0]=='O' && tiles[1][1]=='O' && tiles[2][2] == 'O') {
     winner = new String("O");
     }
    if (tiles[0][2]=='O' && tiles[1][1]=='O' && tiles[2][0] == 'O') {
     winner = new String("O");
    }
    }
    }
     %>

     <% // I am very lost on where this goes in the servlet, I guess that depends on how it gets laid out
     session.setAttribute("tiles", tiles);
     session.setAttribute("winner", winner);
     %>

     <form action="TicTacToe2.jsp" method="post">

     <table border="1" >

     <tbody>

     <%  // This goes in the servlet I am sure
     for (int r=0; r<3; r++) {
     out.println("<tr>");
     for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
     out.println("<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"B" + r + c + "\"" +
    " value=\"" + tiles[r][c] + "\"></td>");
       }
      out.println("</tr>");
     }
     %>

     </tbody>

     </table>

      <%  // Announce winner
      if (!winner.equals("")) {
      out.println("<p>" + winner + " Won!</p>");
      }
      %>

      <p><input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset"></p>

      </form>

      </body>

       </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a wide-open question, and since you are learning I will try to give you some pointers in general.

As a beginner, and for small throw-away code, JSP is fine. In general, as you have surmised, code in the view is messy and considered very bad form these days.

As a result, many many many frameworks have been invented to try to address the problem. Servlets are so low-level that you'd never really write anything real in them either these days. In fact, JSP was an attempt to make writing Servlets easier.

The next big step in web dev was the appearance of MVC frameworks (like Struts) that attempted to apply a well-known OO pattern to web development.

These have evolved into much more complicated systems that attempt to do a lot of work for you, but many of them have grown into giant bloated hairballs of code.

Most Java devs these days have accepted that the server should take the role of data storage, and much of the user interface is moving back to the client (via UI frameworks like Angular, React, etc.) and Javascript/Coffeescript/Clojurescript.

However, if your stated goal is to learn server-side web dev, then I'd recommend looking through various options and seeing what resonates. Struts is old, but relatively easy to learn. Seam is more modern, but has a lot of bloat to get started. Wicket does a nice job of model/view separation.

It's a jungle out there.

My best advice would be to write some console games first using System.in and System.out. Concentrate on clean code. Watch some videos on intentional programming, and avoid the complications of the web stuff until your chops are better.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am looking for, it seems all good programmers say just jump in. I can't do that I need a point of reference. I appreciate your taking the time to help.